# Water flow rate reduction without pressure reduction

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, sprinkler-system

My main water line can deliver 15 gallons per minute at the input side of a sprinkler manifold. What kind of device can I use to deliver a regulated reduced flow rate *without* reducing the water pressure at the manifold valve when the water is flowing? I'd like to reduce the rate to about 10 gallons per minute.

My understanding is that if the water velocity through the sprinkler system is too high, it can result in water hammer or scrubbing, which can damage the pipes.

If there are devices that will do this (regulate rate and maintain pressure), what are they called (for search purposes)? An example or two of something currently available would also be helpful.

Comment: As far as I know, flow is _directly_ related to the combination of pressure and size of pipe. I don't see how you can change any of those variables without affecting the other. If you're concerned about water hammer in the irrigation system, why not just install hammer arrestors to absorb the water hammer? That said, my experience has been that irrigation systems have their shut-off valves at the supply side of the connection, so I wouldn't expect water hammer _in the system itself_ to be a problem at all. There's much in your question that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Water hammer is most often from rapid changes to flow rate - not the velocity only.

Comment: The general case with sprinkles is the supply flow is nor adequate. That is why sprinkler controllers come with several lines or stations ; the supply can maintain good flow pressure for about 6 sprinkler heads. Water hammer is a problem where there is a liquid  moving at velocity in a gas, not  liquid only. Raw gas pipelines have extensive piping  systems to stop liquid moving in the  pipe ; "slug catchers" .  In a gas pipeline like 24" a slug could be several tons .